# What is the required configuration steps to have a Spring Boot application send simple e-mails via AWS SES?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ses, aws-java-sdk, spring-cloud-aws

I have been fighting with this for several hours today.  I started with the documentation at http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sending_mails which doesn't really say a lot about the specific steps.  It just says that the developer can include a Bean XML and then autowire `MailSender`.  I have tried that as well as many variants and have not been able to get it to work using spring-cloud-aws.  I finally resorted to directly including aws-java-sdk-ses and manually configuring the class.

Here is a simple project demonstrating what I've tried:
https://github.com/deinspanjer/aws-ses-test

This project compiles, but when I run it I get:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.awssestest.AwsSesTestApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.MailSender' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'mailSender' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage'
- Bean method 'simpleMailSender' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService'
- Bean method 'javaMailSender' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService'
```

If I try adding javax-mail ( https://github.com/deinspanjer/aws-ses-test/tree/try-with-javax-mail-api ) then the error changes to:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.awssestest.AwsSesTestApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.MailSender' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'mailSender' not loaded because AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.JndiNameProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.HostProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.host) did not find property 'host'
- Bean method 'simpleMailSender' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService'
- Bean method 'javaMailSender' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService'
```

If instead, I try explicitly adding a dependency on aws-java-sdk-ses ( https://github.com/deinspanjer/aws-ses-test/tree/try-with-aws-java-sdk-ses ), I get this error instead:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.awssestest.AwsSesTestApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.MailSender' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'mailSender' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage'
- Bean method 'javaMailSender' in 'MailSenderAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.mail.Session'
- Bean method 'simpleMailSender' in 'MailSenderAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.mail.simplemail.SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender'
```

For this error, I tried adding a `@Qualifier("simpleMailSender")` annotation to the `@Autowired`, but it did not help.

I hope someone might be able to steer me in the right direction.

Comment: It seems you are missing to import the @ImportResource("/aws-mail.xml") on your AwsSesTestApplication class.

Comment: I just tried adding that annotation to the application class, but it doesn't change the error message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may try below steps to fix your issue. I tried these changes in the [forked repo](https://github.com/skadyan/aws-ses-test) from you and it works for me.

1. Add dependency "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses" in `pom.xml` file.
2. Create an auto configuration class to configure the mail sender bean. Below is example. The `AWSCredentialsProvider` is configured and provided by `spring-cloud-starter-aws` out-of-the-box.

.

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleMailAutoConfig {

    @Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
        return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                // Replace US_WEST_2 with the AWS Region you're using for
                // Amazon SES.
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MailSender mailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService ses) {
        return new SimpleEmailServiceMailSender(ses);
    }
}
```

3. Use spring API to send mail using the configured mail sender.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

If you need to use `JavaMailSender` instead of `MailSender` (for instance when you want to send attachments), simply configure `SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender` instead of `SimpleEmailServiceMailSender`.

Like this:

```
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService ses) {
        return new SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender(ses);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please assist in defining the mailsender bean with `JavaMailSender` instead of `MailSender`?. I'm trying to send HTML emails with SES. But the `MailSender` only allows plain text emails. How to specify this SES config to `JavaMailSender`?

Comment: What is `SimpleEmailServiceMailSender`? I can't find this class.

Comment: This class is from library https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws. You may refer to the pom.xml in the forked repo for dependencies

Comment: what is the spring boot version required ? also how can i get MailSender dependency ?

Comment: You may refer to pom.xml in the forked repository. I think it was 1.5.x.

Comment: ses dependency is now updated to software.amazon.awssdk.ses

Answer (score 4):

I used AWS SES in a Spring Boot web project some time ago, but I haven't used Spring Cloud AWS to integrate my application with the mail service.

Instead I simply included `spring-boot-starter-mail` among the project dependencies (pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then I set SMTP server parameters in my `application.properties`. In my case I used these properties:

```
spring.mail.host=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.smtps.auth=true
spring.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
spring.mail.username=<my-user>
spring.mail.password=<my-password>
```

**Note**: server host and port may vary.

Spring Boot will create a default `JavaMailSender` instance, configuring it with the previos parametes. You can use this object to send emails...

Probably this in not the best approach to AWS SES integration with a Spring Boot application, but it works fine for me.

Comment: I thought about doing the same, but I wanted to avoid using the smtp interface for SES. Thanks for the input though, very likely it might help someone else down the line.

Comment: @deinspanjer why do you want to avoid using SMTP? (just for information...)

Comment: Because Amazon recommends using the SES API instead when possible, primarily due to performance considerations.  See the note at the beginning of this doc section: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.1.RELEASE/#_sending_mails

Comment: Take a look at this Gist: https://gist.github.com/ShigeoTejima/f2997f57405010c3caca it may be useful...

Comment: Yep, I did see this, and it helped in getting me started, but as the commenter said, it looks like the API has changed since that was posted, and it doesn't work out of the box any more.

Comment: the `spring.mail.protocol=smtps` did the trick for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add AWS-Java-sdk to your project
2. Setup AWS credentials (Keys) on your machine
3. Create SendEmailRequest
4. SendEmailRequest#.sendEmail(request)

p.s. You don't need any JavaMail here. You can wrap it to beans in Spring in any desired way.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should have been a bit more clear that I was specifically looking for help with getting spring-cloud-aws working as is shown in my example project.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through Application.properties also. Make Sure that You are not in the sandbox in AWS SES.

1. Verify your E-mail Adress or Domain for sending Email through SES.Go to SES DashBoard and select "Email Addresses".(For testing, you can Send a Demo email From SES DashBoard--> Email Addresses --> Send a Test email).
2. Create 'Access Key Id' and 'Secret access key'.(Without this keys You cannot send mail. You will get 535-Error).

3.Now put the keys in your application.properties. As Shown below

```
`spring.mail.host=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com(Your Hosting region)
spring.mail.username=<Access Key Id>
spring.mail.password=<Secret access key>`
```

If you are using MimeMessage then set the Sending mail ID as given below:

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
helper.setFrom("yourmailID@yourDomain.com");
```

Hope It helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to @davioooh answer,if anybody is using smtp interface of aws instead of aws sdk api,--
If you are using Port 465,then use protocol as smtps
But,If you are using Port 25,587,then you use protocol as smtp
It is mandatory.

If you are not using SMTPS while using port 465,then you will get exception in your springboot application.(Because,while using Port 465 client has to initiate the TLS while transferring the mail,so you have to mention SMTPS in your application.properties file.

Similarly,you are not required to use SMTPS while using Port 25,587 because in this case server first responds to the client that it is tls enabled or not,then the client initiates a tls encryption.So,you only have to use SMTP in case of Port 25,587.